# how do I conditionally disable a button kendo.ui grid based on values from model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo.ui grid and I have a custom command to cretae a button. I need to disable the button based on two values in the model data.

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("loadDataForEdit")).Width(20);
```

I tried just wrapping it in an if statement but it didn't like that.

Has anyone else needed to do this before and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a client template to accomplish this where `Disabled` is a property on the model I bound to the grid (sorry about the formatting.  It's a long string in my razor view)

```
c.Bound(f => f.Status).ClientTemplate("#if(Disabled) {#<a class='btn btn-small' href='Enable/Index/#=LoginId#' >Enable</a> #}" +
" else {#<a class='btn btn-small btn-danger' href='Disable/Index/#=LoginId#'>Disable</a>#}#".ToString());
```

Comment: Perfect! Great solution. I wish I could get my head around this product better. ugh